# Qt 5.7 Tagging alternating words in text element to be bold

Tags: qt, qtquick2, qt-quick

So I want something equivalent to

```
<p>The <b>quick</b> brown <b>fox</b> jumps <b>over</b> the <b>lazy</b> dog</p>
```

The **quick** brown **fox** jumps **over** the **lazy** dog

I know I can achieve this with a Flow in combination with a bunch of Text elements, one for each contiguous block of bold or non-bold text. I was just wondering if there was something cleaner.

Comment: This is such an esoteric request that I strongly doubt QML offers a built-in way of doing such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [QML Text item documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-text.html).
There's even an example:

```
Text {
    text: "<b>Hello</b> <i>World!</i>"
}
```

Copy the following in the awesome [QML web editor](https://qmlweb.github.io/)

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
  width: 400; height: 100

  Text {
     text: "The <b>quick</b> brown <b>fox</b> jumps <b>over</b> the <b>lazy</b> dog"
     anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
     anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm thanks for the response. I think I was running into this bug https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-30917 on OSX where bold custom font loading was not working. Tested on linux and it seems to work.